# ASP.NET Core MVC. Stripe.StripeException: 'No such charge: 'txn_1HewOXGhhS4IDSpp9ifQ6hYq''

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET Core MVC. I include Stripe, pay works fine, when I try to refund a payment, an exception is displayed. Using debugin shows different values ​​on line 89 Areas/Admin/Controllers/OrderController, the Сharge value has a different meaning than it should be.I went through the whole program through the debugger and I don't know what to do

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8YHg.png)

Comment: `the Сharge value has a different meaning than it should be` What should it be?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object suggests that `txn` and `ch` are different prefixes for different types. Presumably you are getting the ID from the wrong type of object. https://gist.github.com/fnky/76f533366f75cf75802c8052b577e2a5

Comment: mjwills Thx a lot! I solved this problem!